# Ubuntu 18.04 Cifs Mount not showing files on boot

Tags: permissions, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I've just moved over to Linux (Ubunutu 18.04) from Windows.

I have a WDNAS which I have mounted and works fine here.

```
mkdir mnt/NAS
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

```
//192.168.1.17/wd_nas mnt/wdnas cifs credentials=/home/ubuntu/login.cred,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

Running `sudo mount -a` mounts as expected and I can see the share fine. It also appears in the gui Nautilus file manager.

The issue is, after a reboot the mount appears to have gone. It doesn't appear in file manager. It only works when run `sudo mount -a`.

`df -h` shows it mounted. `//192.168.1.17/wd_nas  3T  1.2T  1.5T  30% /mnt/wd_nas`

```
cat /var/log/syslog/ |grep wd_nas
Mar  6 20:51:22 ubuntu systemd[1]: Mounting /mnt/wd_nas
Mar  6 20:51:22 ubuntu systemd[1]: Mounted /mnt/wd_nas
```

If I run `ls -la /mnt/wd_nas` I can see the files I have placed there as test but if I navigate via the gui (nautilus file manager) I can't see anything?

So my first assumption was permissions but I checked and confirmed. Directories and all subs are chown to user with rw access. Googling frantically for days, I've tried almost **everything** I could find. Even topics relating the network not booting before fstab is being run, so adding _netdev and even configuring systemd. I've even tried to create a bash script to sleep for 20s and run mount -a via cron at reboot. Nothing! Although it doesn't at all appear to be related.

Now I'm here. Would you be able to help?

Comment: Have you tried the `nofail` option? Other than that, your fstab entry is similar to mine.

Comment: Yep, I've added it. I also even tried specifying the version. `vers=1.0` or even `vers=2.0`.. And so many others with no luck :( I've been told it may be relating to the file system on the wd nas? but I'm sure it supports Linux and even when I run `sudo mount - a` it does actually mount just not automatically on boot.

Comment: Anybody able to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my UBUNTU 18.04 server and for my Synology NAS i have create 2 files script :

after install

```
apt-get install cifs-utils
```

The first:

```
nano ./mount.nas.sh 
mount -t cifs //192.168.1.xxx/home /mnt/NAS-xxx -o username=philippe,credentials=/home/philippe/.credential.phil,domain=WORKGROUP,vers=1.0

chmod 755 ./mount.nas.sh
```

the second :

```
nano ./.credential.phil
username=<username on NAS>
password=<Password>

 chmod 700 ./credential.phil
```

all are OK for a backup.shell script
for test use

```
umount -f -l /mnt/NAS-xxx
df -h
```

Comment: Welcome to ask ubuntu. Please try to use proper formatting. I have fixed it for you but in the future when putting code in a post either leave a line blank and then start each line of the code block with 4 spaces (as I did here). Or if you just and single lines of code you can use " ` " before and after the code snippet to post inline `like so` .

Answer (score 1):

I've figure it out after a painful week.

fstab was creating the mount point at `/mnt` which i believe is the root dir. So that is why `df -h` was showing it mounted, as it was, just elsewhere.

Was - `//192.168.1.17/wd_nas mnt/wdnas`

Now - `//192.168.1.17/wd_nas /home/user/mnt/wdnas`

Found this definition here in this forum..

*"Using the /mnt directory should only work if the drive is a local volume rather than a network share or removable device."*

Apologies, i'm new to Linux.